# C# ASP.NET Core 2.1/Entity Framework: Entity collention dosen't saving

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a simple ASP.NET Core (2.1) API that implements get & post methods with objects of this class:

```
public class Command
{
    public uint id { get; set; }
    public string command { get; set; }
    public List<Client> clients { get; set; }
}
public class Client
{
    public uint id { get; set; }
    public string nameofpc { get; set; }
}

public class CommandContext : DbContext
{
    public CommandContext(DbContextOptions<CommandContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Command> Commands { get; set; }
}
```

I send POST request with this entity:

```
var command = new Command()
{
    command = "/start^cmd.exe",
    clients = new List<Client>()
    {
        new Client()
        {
            nameofpc = "Zerumi"
        }
    }
};
// Converting to JSON and sending to api...
```

In CommandController.cs located this code:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CommandController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly CommandContext _context;

    public CommandController(CommandContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Command>>> GetCommands()
    {
        return await _context.Commands.ToListAsync();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Command>> PostCommand([FromBody] Command item)
    {
        _context.Commands.Add(item);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetCommand), new { item.id }, item);
    }
}
```

The item parameter of the postcommand method is no different from what was sent. However, if i send GET request to /command after saving, i will get this:

```
[{"id":1,"command":"/start^cmd.exe","clients":null}]
```

Why colleсtion is null and what i need to do for good entity saving?

Comment: Use `Include` in the Get method.

Comment: Or enable lazy loading (use caution!) `services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
        options.UseLazyLoadingProxies()`. Ideally, you should use view models or project your results into anonymous types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, it seems that something is missing, but maybe you configure stuff in OnModelCreating, hard to tell when I don't have your code. And you should use Pascal-casing in your EF-code and replace uint with int.

Then you should add DTO-classes (model-classes) for both Command and Client. Decorate each property in DTO with e.g.

```
[JsonProperty("command")]
```

in order to maintain correct casing (camel-casing).

```
public class Command
{
   public uint id { get; set; }
   public string command { get; set; }

   public List<Client> clients { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
  public int CommandId { get; set; } // foreign key

  [ForeignKey(nameof(CommandId))]
  public Command Command { get; set; }

  public uint id { get; set; }
  public string nameofpc { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The inverse property configuration is not necessary.

Comment: Output: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'command' with type 'WebApp1.Models.Command'. Path 'clients[0]'. And clients also are null... (Strange, I renamed the parameters in classes, but in output old names)

Comment: You should not use EF-enitites to produce your JSON, the contract will easily break if you change stuff. Create DTO-classes for both Command and Client and use them instead. In DTO for Client, do not add reference back to CommandDto.

Comment: To make it work for now, you can add a [JsonIgnore] on Client.Command

Comment: Or configure you serializer to ignore reference loops `(services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore)`. But you really should use ViewModels (DTOs) as @RoarS. stated.

Comment: @RoarS. the adding all of those `[JsonProperty]` attributes is a waste of time. The point of types consumed and produced directly by controllers is that their properties lineup with the client. Use that attribute when you need to customize something, like return one property in place of another.

Comment: Everything turned out to be easier than it seems... When I was looking for information about DTOs, I found this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-4) that described my problem. EF does not load collections when I try to get the whole object. You need a separate request to get this collection (e.g. Include(x => x.Clients)). But thanks for answer

Comment: Excellent, glad you made it. And thanks to @AluanHaddad for the collab!

Comment: @RoarS. my pleasure. Cheers!